# Ember cleanup on leaving route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I want to make some cleanup when i leave route, like stopping timers. For that i need an event that triggers when leaving the route, and i need access to instance of controller inside of that event.

There is an `exit` event, but it doesn't get any arguments, and `this.get('controller')` inside it doesn't work too - returns *undefined*.

Is there a proper way for obtaining controller instance in the `exit` event, or, maybe, another event that i don't know of?

I setup [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crUFE/7/) with an example of what i want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling `this.controllerFor('home')`. You can try it [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lcoq/crUFE/8/).

This is a little bit annoying, so a [pull request has been merged](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1913) recently that allows you to directly use `this.controller`, as you can see [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lcoq/crUFE/9/).

Comment: I liked the `this.controller`! Thanks a lot! BTW They are going to deprecate the `controllerFor` thing..

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko Where did you see that ? The API had just been documented: http://goo.gl/7jXuI

Comment: I read it somewhere in the internet and also saw it in the source code, but now I see that it is `ControllerMixin.controllerFor` which is deprecated!! My bad..