# ember-data unsaved model is not discarded when navigating back with the back button

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, back-button

I have an ember app with a data model and the usual CRUD views/routes/controllers for listing and adding new items.

When I click 'add new' from the index page, I get the expected form, with 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons. If I press cancel, the view goes back to the index view and the model is not saved, as expected.

This is the code of the new items controller:

```
App.ItemsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    saveChanges: function() {
      this.model.save();
      this.transitionTo('items');
    },
    cancel: function() {
      this.model.rollback(); // how to run this when the back button is pressed?
      this.transitionTo('items');
    },
  },
});
```

But if I press the back button, I also end up in the index page, but an extra empty row appears in the index listing, corresponding to the new record that was not saved in the 'new' view. This record was not persisted to the data layer, but it somehow still exists in memory, and `this.store.find('items')` returns a collection that includes it. If I refresh the page, the blank row disappears. Also, as stated above, if I exit the form using the cancel button, the record is discarded, because in the 'cancel' action method I invoke `this.model.rollback()`.

So bottomline, I guess I would have to rollback the model when the back button is pressed, but there's no route callback that I know of to hook some code to this event.

In case it's important, I'm using Ember 1.9.1, Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.15-canary, Handlebars 2.0.0, jQuery 1.10.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is the second time in a row that I post to stackoverflow and I find the answer shortly after, so I guess I should refrain from asking here unless I'm literally clueless and hopeless ;)

Thanks to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873452/ember-cleanup-on-leaving-route), I found out that there is an `exit` event on the route. So the key to solve this is on the route, and not in the controller. I ended up putting the model rollback in the route's exit event method, as shown below:

**UPDATE:** @NicholasJohn16 points out that it is better to use the [`deactivate`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_deactivate) hook, instead of `exit`. See the details in the comments below. The code example has been changed accordingly.

```
App.ItemsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('item', {
      title: 'Untitled',
      status: 'new',
    });
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    model = this.controllerFor('notifications.new').get('model');
    model.rollback();
  },
});
```

Once this is done, you can even remove the `model.rollback()` call from the cancel action in the controller, and leave just the `transitionTo('items')` call. Since the route's `deactivate` event will always be called, regardless of the way you leave the view, the model will always be discarded.

Comment: [Deactivate](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_deactivate) maybe a better option.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @NicholasJohn16. But could you elaborate briefly what are the differences and why is it better?

Comment: The exit hook is a private property. I dont believe its meant to be overridden. Deactivate is public however and can be used in the same manor.

Comment: `model.rollback();` is now `model.rollbackAttributes();`

Comment: Be aware that model.rollbackAttributes() do NOT support rollback relationships and DS.attrs not supported officially... So enjoy... I've been headache of this for a long time

Comment: Even better I think is [resetController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_resetController). `deactivate` is not called when switching to another model using the same route, e.g `item/1/edit` -> `item/2/edit`